# Saltstack local installation progress for orchestration

Tags: salt-stack

How can I do view of progress salt installation for local console?
I use orchestration for install software on several servers, it took two hours.
How I can do output of `saltstack` orchestration more useful?

> 1. current stage
> 2. summary output, like:
>
>    - state1  - Success
>    - state2  - Success
>    - state3  - Failed, etc

Comment: Are you running the `highstate` command remotely from a salt-master?

Comment: I run command like this
salt-run state.orchestrate orchestration.deploy

I want to get output like
 1. Orchestration was began
 2. Database on server1 was deployed,  on server2 .. server n
       All databases deployed 
 ...
  All state by steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it catch event  from salt bus.

There are two problem which didn't resolv yet:
 - event sent after state was applyed ( so if  state get a lot of time, there isn't any message about it)
 - some state doesn't send any additional info and will be displayed as N\A

Comment: Do you have any code to share? I'm struggling with this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running `state.orchestrate` from your salt-master (as said in comments), you will not be able to view the output from your salt-minion's highstate in real-time.

You will need to SSH into a specific minion and run `salt-call state.highstate` to see the real-time output from that specific minion.

Comment: Do I have any opportunity to get events from orchestration in real time?
My orchestration gets is much time, so I want to know which steps is going  now.

Comment: What about any summary custom output for orchestration ? Does it possible?

Comment: You can query the state of any running jobs with the jobs runner, but there's no real time streaming of minion output. I'm not sure what your second question means.

Comment: is it possible to get a short  summary at the end? Example,  15 steps of 15 was successfull,  or  10 steps of 15 sucessful, and failed on 11 step. I mean short report for fast analyze.

Comment: You're looking for the minion config option `state_output: terse`